# Acessar objetos diferentes dentro de um array

Tags: javascript

Como posso acessar esse objecto do jeito certo?
Tenho esses dois cenários

```
Object
  Array[2]
   Object: {"code": "a", cor: "vermelha"}
   Object: {"code": "b", cor"azul"}
```

e

```
Object
  Array[1]
   Object: {"code": "b", cor: "azul" }
```

se eu fizer cabelo.propriedade[0].cor
vou ter o retorno `vermelha` e `azul`

como posso trazer sempre a cor `azul`?

Comment: Não está claro qual é a sua condição de seleção. Você precisa pegar sempre o último elemento?

Comment: eu preciso trazer sempre  o objeto que tiver a cor azul, q no primeiro cenario está na posição [1] e depois na posição [0]

Answer (score 1):

Basta você filtrar seu objeto com a condição que desejar. Se neste caso você precisa de todos os objetos que possuem `cor: azul`, basta fazer:

```
let list = cabelo.propriedade.filter(item => {
    return (item.cor == "azul");
});
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
const cabelo = {
    "propriedade": [
        {
            "code": "a",
            "cor": "vermelha"
        }, {
            "code": "b",
            "cor": "azul"
        }
    ]
};

let list = cabelo.propriedade.filter(item => {
    return (item.cor == "azul");
});

console.log(list);
```

Se houverem mais registros que satisfaçam tal condição, todos eles serão retornados:

```js
const cabelo = {
    "propriedade": [
        {
            "code": "a",
            "cor": "vermelha"
        }, {
            "code": "b",
            "cor": "azul"
        }, {
            "code": "c",
            "cor": "azul"
        }
    ]
};

let list = cabelo.propriedade.filter(item => {
    return (item.cor == "azul");
});

console.log(list);
```